# The LINQ expression could not be translated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table called `Orders` and a list called `Customers`. `Orders` has a property `CustomerId`. Now I want to get all orders of customers that are in my `Customers` list.

This is what I tried:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers; // list of customers
List<Order> orders = dbContext.Orders.Where(x => customers.Any(y => y.Id == x.CustomerId)).Include(x => x.someOtherTable).ToList();
```

For some reason this always results in an exception saying that the LINQ expression could not be translated. My assumption is that this is due to the fact that the CustomerId in Order is nullable. I am not sure though.

**Order**:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int? CustomerId { get; set; } // has to be nullable
...
```

**Customer**:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; } // has to be nullable
...
```

This is only a small snippet due to simplicity.

Comment: How do you get `IEnumerable<Customer> customers;`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the reason is that `customers` is `IEnumerable`, not `IQueryable`, so LINQ can not transale to SQL code your collection.

Convert your `IEnumerable<Customer>` to id list:

```
int[] ids = customers.Select(o => o.id).ToArray();
```

And `Where` with `Contains`:

```
List<Order> orders = dbContext.Orders.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))
                                     .Include(x => x.someOtherTable).ToList();
```

Comment: `.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))`

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was using a read only property [x.Id] in the linq statement.

In my partial class:

```
public partial class Paddock
{
   public int Id => EntityId;
}
```

My linq query with error:

```
var paddocks = _context.Paddocks.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

Changing it to the true property fixed it for me:

```
var paddocks = _context.Paddocks.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.EntityId)).ToList();
```