# The LINQ expression could not be translated - Error with Nullable Id field

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, controller, linq-expressions

In my controller, I'm trying to get all of the people records back that belong to a certain company, I'm attempting to do that like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("getCompanyPeople/{companyId}")]
public ActionResult<List<CompanyPeopleDTO>> getCompanyPeople(int companyId)
{
  List<CompanyPeopleDTO> companyPeople = _context.TblPeople.Select(e => new CompanyPeopleDTO()
    {
      PersonId = e.PersonId,
      NamePrefix = e.NamePrefix,
      FirstName = e.FirstName,
      LastName = e.LastName,
      NameSuffix = e.NameSuffix,
      peopleTypeDesc = e.PeopleTypeNavigation.PeopleTypeDesc,
      contactTypeDesc = e.ContactTypeNavigation.ContactTypeDesc
    }).Where(e => e.CompanyId == companyId).ToList();

    return companyPeople;
 }
```

However, when testing this, I get an error back that says:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<TblPeople>
    .LeftJoin(
        outer: DbSet<TblPeopleTypes>, 
        inner: t => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(t, "PeopleType"), 
        outerKeySelector: t0 => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(t0, "PeopleTypeId"), 
        innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<TblPeople, TblPeopleTypes>(
            Outer = o, 
            Inner = i
        ))
    .LeftJoin(
        outer: DbSet<TblContactTypes>, 
        inner: t => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(t.Outer, "ContactType"), 
        outerKeySelector: t1 => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(t1, "ContactTypeId"), 
        innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TblPeople, TblPeopleTypes>, TblContactTypes>(
            Outer = o, 
            Inner = i
        ))
    .Where(t => (Nullable<int>)new CompanyPeopleDTO{ 
        PersonId = t.Outer.Outer.PersonId, 
        NamePrefix = t.Outer.Outer.NamePrefix, 
        FirstName = t.Outer.Outer.FirstName, 
        LastName = t.Outer.Outer.LastName, 
        NameSuffix = t.Outer.Outer.NameSuffix, 
        peopleTypeDesc = t.Outer.Inner.PeopleTypeDesc, 
        contactTypeDesc = t.Inner.ContactTypeDesc 
    }
    .CompanyId != null && new CompanyPeopleDTO{ 
        PersonId = t.Outer.Outer.PersonId, 
        NamePrefix = t.Outer.Outer.NamePrefix, 
        FirstName = t.Outer.Outer.FirstName, 
        LastName = t.Outer.Outer.LastName, 
        NameSuffix = t.Outer.Outer.NameSuffix, 
        peopleTypeDesc = t.Outer.Inner.PeopleTypeDesc, 
        contactTypeDesc = t.Inner.ContactTypeDesc 
    }
    .CompanyId == __companyId_0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'
```

I think this could possibly be due to the fact that the companyId could be null. I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59526624/the-linq-expression-could-not-be-translated), but it didn't work - it gives me the same error as before, and the more I look at it, I don't think what I am trying to do really relates to that question.

I have tested this without checking the companyId on the person record - that successfully returns all people records, but obviously, that's not what I want.

Comment: Is a  `CompanyId`  property in the Person entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var companyPeople = _context.TblPeople
.Where(e => e.CompanyId == companyId)
.Select(e => new CompanyPeopleDTO()
    {
      PersonId = e.PersonId,
      NamePrefix = e.NamePrefix,
      FirstName = e.FirstName,
      LastName = e.LastName,
      NameSuffix = e.NameSuffix,
      peopleTypeDesc = e.PeopleTypeNavigation.PeopleTypeDesc,
      contactTypeDesc = e.ContactTypeNavigation.ContactTypeDesc
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: That did it! Of course it was something so simple! Thanks for the help!