# Linq left join using GroupJoin not working in fluentAPI

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

My query expression is working fine when executed.

```
var topQuery1 = (
    from rov in context.Rocks
        .Where(x => eIds.Contains(x.RockId))

    join ro in context.Rocks
        .Where(x => x.Break == "OUT")
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp)
        on
           new { rov.WorkerId, rov.Flatter } equals
           new { ro.WorkerId, ro.Flatter }
           into _rovOut

    from rovOut in _rovOut.DefaultIfEmpty()

    join ao in context.Workers()
        on rov.WorkerId equals ao.WorkerId
           into _profile

    from profile in _profile.DefaultIfEmpty()

    select new { rov, rovOut, profile }
);
```

I translate the above code into this fluentAPI and not working as expected.

```
var topQuery2 = context.Rocks.Where(x => eIds.Contains(x.RockId))
.GroupJoin(context.Workers(),
    r => r.WorkerId,
    p => p.WorkerId,
    (a, b) => new { profile = b.SingleOrDefault(), rov = a })
.GroupJoin(context.Rocks.Where(x => x.Break == "OUT").OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp),
    a => new { a.rov.WorkerId, a.rov.Flatter },
    b => new { b.WorkerId, b.Flatter },
    (a, b) => new { rovOut = b.SingleOrDefault(), rov = a.rov, profile = a.profile });
```

It generates error:

> Error creating query string: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(x => __eIds_0
> .Contains(x.RockId))
> .GroupJoin(
> inner: DbSet(),
> outerKeySelector: r => r.WorkerId,
> innerKeySelector: p => p.WorkerId,
> resultSelector: (a, b) => new {
> profile = b.SingleOrDefault(),
> rov = a
> })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly
> by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList',
> or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038
> for more information..

**[EDIT]**

I end up using LeftJoin from this url https://velog.io/@prediction/EF-CORE-Left-Join-Extension and everything is working now.

Comment: Your query in the current format contains a method that's not supported or is missing a method. You will either have to rewrite it and find out which method is causing this or add that method as the error message tells you.

Comment: the second .GroupJoin is causing the error but I don't really sure which part the problem is

Comment: 1) Install trial ReSharper and convert to method chain into single click 2) Ask Chat GPT to do that 3) Do not convert to method syntax queries which use several joins, it is ugly and non-maintainable.

Comment: Create a navigation property Rock.Worker and you don't need the second join anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in `eIds` field, where and how you calculate it? (If you post it I will review this answer)

A [common problem with lists and contains in linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59526624/the-linq-expression-could-not-be-translated) is this:

```
var eIds = 
        myContext.SomeTable
        .Select(x=>x.id)
        
var otherQuery = 
        myContext.SomeTable2
        .Where(x=>eIds.contains(x.Id2))
        .ToList()
```

This throws an error in Linq to SQL because ids can't be traslated to SQL in second query.

Resolve using `.ToList()` before using `eIds` field, like this:

```
var eIds = 
        myContext.SomeTable
        .Select(x=>x.id)
        .ToList()

        
var otherQuery = 
        myContext.SomeTable2
        .Where(x=>eIds.contains(x.Id2))
        .ToList()
```

Comment: var eIds = File.ReadAllLines(path);
It comes from a file and never be empty e.g.
R0PF839
R0PF833
R0PF880